# From this React Docs example, how does Clock become a reusable component without a constructor method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I thought all valid ES6 classes must be instantiated with a constructor.

Additionally, how does the sub-class `Clock` have access to the `render()` method of the parent class `React.Component` without calling `super()`?

```
 class Clock extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.props.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

http://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/zKRGpo?editors=0010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the `super` constructor is called - there's no need to call it explicitly, unless redefining the method in this class.

The render method defined here overrides the one in the base class.

Comment: Thanks.  I typically accept an answer after I'm able to understand it. Pending

Comment: @Zach is that an indirect request for clarification?

Comment: Not at all. Just a curtesy note to you on my speed of processing. Ideally correct answers should receive acceptance asap. Apologies

Comment: I wouldn't say there's any rush to accept an answer - if anything's unclear, let me know (and update the question, if necessary).

Comment: Ok. Noted. Thanks. Personally I assumed answerers deserve and appreciate rapid gratification.